# make operation on two successive elements in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `A= [4     7    10]` what I want to do is to sum every two elements and put the result in a new vector. So for example vector `B= [11,17]` which is the the sum of 4+7 and 7+10.

So if anyone could advise me how can I do this without loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative that will be easy to generalize should you want to add groups of 3 or 4 etc in the future:

```
n = 2
conv(A, ones(1, n), 'valid')
```

Comment: Note that some versions of Matlab don't support the option `'valid'` in `conv`. In that case, you have to manually remove the `n-1` first and last elements in the result: `result =  conv(A, ones(1,n)); result = result(n:end-n+1);`

Comment: @Dan what if I want to sum every two elements and divide the answer by 2 so in the above example `B` will (4+7)/2 and (7+10)/2?

Comment: um... just divide the result by 2. `conv(A, ones(1, n), 'valid')./2`

Answer (score 5):

In my view it is:

```
B = A(1:end-1) + A(2:end);
```

Comment: @matheburg what if I want to sum every two elements and divide the answer by 2 so in the above example B will (4+7)/2 and (7+10)/2?

Comment: Do you talk about `B = (A(1:end-1) + A(2:end))/2;`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
B = A(:,1:end-1) + A(:,2:end);
```

This code doesn't limit to just row vector. It will work on MxN matrix as well.

Comment: Isn't this wrong and even throws an error for odd `length(A) > 3`?

Comment: So there is no use for my answer anymore... ;-)